# How can I compute set operations on spans?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In a course on digital control by a less-than-helpful teacher, we're learning about Kalman decomposition. To compute the transformation matrix T, you first find the controllability and observability matrix P and Q, and then

$$T = [T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4]\\
T_1= \text{im}(P) \cap \text{ker}(Q)\\
T_2= \text{im}(P) \setminus \text{im}(T_1)\\
T_3= \text{ker}(W) \setminus \text{im}(T_1)\\
T_4= \text{im}([T_1, T_2, T_3]^\perp)\\
$$

The problem is that he never explained how to compute these intersections and complements, except by inspection (on trivial unit vector examples). Some internet searches did not turn up much useful either.

Intuitively, for most trivial examples you can just take the union/intersection/complement of the column vectors in the span, discarding (scaled) duplicates. But there are probably cases where this does not work?

Comment: Those computations are standard fare early in a linear algebra course. You might find help in one of many on line resources, including some full texts.

Comment: I dug up my linear algebra book, and it's not in there as far as I can tell. They certainly never taught us. And as said, I could not find the online resources you mentioned.